# Failing to replace backslash

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a string coming in to a method that represents domain username, from razor view, called via JS:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function editResource() {
...
            var user = '@Context.User.Identity.Name';
            $.post(url, ... skipped
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
public string SaveDeprecatedResource(string resource, string newResource, string description, string user, string ticket)
    {
        user = user.Replace("\\", "\\\\"); // how do I replace with double backslash?
```

user that comes to controller equals "DOMAIN\v-user"

user object is string:

```
user.GetType()
{Name = "String" FullName = "System.String"}
    [System.RuntimeType]: {Name = "String" FullName = "System.String"}
```

I need to insert it insert it to db (LINQ), but it eats the backslash. Basically I need to replace the `\` with `\\`, I am failing to do so. What am I doing wrong?

```
user.Contains(@"\")
false
user.Contains(@"\\")
false
user.Contains("\\")
false
user.Contains('\\')
false
```

---

EDIT, so the backslash is not a backslash, but ie `\v` is treated as vertical tab. Anyway, after the backslash can be any letter of the alphabet. How do I universally handle it?

Comment: _"coming in to a method"_ - where does it come from and what does it look like exactly?

Comment: Do you set the DOMAIN\user somewhere, or is it read from a textbox or some other UI control? If you set it in code, you need to include a @ at the front, like user = @"DOMAIN\user";

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape backslash when you are saving the data into DB.

```
user = @"DOMAIN\user"
```